# Firebase RealTime Database Rules using regular expression for custom ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a requirement that users can only write to their account node in the RT database. Normally this would work:

```
  "accounts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    },
```

However, the requirement is that the uid from Authentication is stored inside "accounts" prefixed with "US_".

So, I've tried this:

```
  "accounts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": $uid.matches(/^US_/) + "auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    },
```

and this:

```
  "accounts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === /^US_/auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    },
```

The 2nd seems closer to working and the error is:

> Error saving rules - Line 44: invalid flag after regular expression

I am wondering if this is even possible?

**UPDATE**

This parsed correctly, but it does not seem to work (I cannot get the rule to pass):

```
  "accounts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === 'US_' + 'auth.uid'",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    },
  },
```

**Database Structure**

```
  accounts:
    uid: "US_blah",
    createdAt: <datetime>,
    username: "MickeyMouse"
```

Comment: "the uid from Authentication is stored inside "accounts" prefixed with "US_" -> can you show how is your database structure corresponding to this statement?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Added to the end of the question

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, is `username` at the same level than `uid`? Or it is one of its children?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for the quick response, but I managed to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did not need a regular expression. This works:

```
  "accounts": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === 'US_' + auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    },
```